# i created notification function and getting this error "Undefined index: user" how to solve it?

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, notifications, undefined

im creating notification function,and when the user replied to a post it should send notification to the owner of the post. But there was an error showing
Undefined index: question. may i know how to solve it.

app.blade

```
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
 aria- expanded="false">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"> </span> notification <span 
 class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications)}}</span>
</a>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

   <li>  
   @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
      @include('layouts.partials.notification.'.snake_case(class_basename($notification->type))) 
   @endforeach

    </li>
 </ul>
```

model

```
   class RepliedToPost extends Notification
  {
   use Queueable;
     protected $postqs;


public function __construct($postqs)
{
    $this->postqs=$postqs;

}


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}


public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
      'postqs'=>$this->postqs,
      'user'=>$notifiable

    ];
}

}
```

notification blade file

```
  {{$notification->data['user']['name']}} commmented on 
  {{$notification>data['postqs']['question']}}
```

Comment: If index is undefined, check if exists, or define any default value.

Comment: postqs table is not empty,it has data. i have no idea why it is not storing in notification table

Answer (score 0):

"question" is not present in data['postqs'] array

Comment: in database. it stored like this {"postqs":[],"user":{"id":1,"name":"ww","email":"s...

Comment: The postqs array is empty, that's why you are getting the error. There is no data present for postqs.

Comment: may i know how to fix it?

Comment: I think your postqs table in  database is empty. You can store some data and then test. Also, before accessing it, first check if it exists. If you are satisfied with the answer please accept it.

Comment: no. the postqs table is not empty,it has data. i have no idea why it is not storing in notification table